# How to build application targetting .Net 4/4.5 on CentOs

Tags: msbuild

I have a lot of legacy code that builds fine on Windows with .Net 4.5

I am trying to build the same on CentOS with dotnet-sdk for automation and licensing issues.

Following the Microsoft link after installing the required packages, this command fails

```
$ dotnet msbuild  sharpTest.sln

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.301/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1216,5): error MSB3644: The reference
assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
(SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework
Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

Since I installed `dotnet-sdk-5`, it seems the solution fails to build. But I could not locate `.Net framework 4` for CentOS

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's referencing .NETFramework. .NETFramework V4.0 is not xplat and therefore not available on anything else than windows. You should try to re-target your solution to net5.0 and make it independent of Windows specific dependencies.

To re-target to net5.0 try the [`dotnet upgrade-assistant`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/upgrade-assistant) (it's a dotnet tool).  Do this on a windows machine first. To address any windows dependencies that won't work outside windows or .NetFramework see the [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/core/porting/)

Comment: I believe a simple change of config files won't help, right ? I'll need to redo some code, resolve dependencies etc.

Comment: Yeah you are right. If you have anything that deps on any windows specific feature then you need to fix that as well.